# How to create a PDF document with the following HTML string with SVG?

Tags: java, html, pdf, svg, flying-saucer

I am trying to convert an HTML String into a PDF document. But only the text part is being printed into the PDF but not SVG. Here is what I have tried.

1. Convert the HTML String into org.w3c.dom.Document
2. Using Flying-Saucer to generate the pdf

> ```
> import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
> import java.io.FileOutputStream;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.io.OutputStream;
> import java.io.StringReader;
> import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
> import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
> import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
> import org.w3c.dom.Document;
> import org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.SharedContext;
> import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
> import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
> import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
> import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
> ```

```
    public class PDFCreator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PDFCreator pdfCreator = new PDFCreator();
        String html = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta name=\"generator\" content=\"HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 2009-12-01), see jtidy.sourceforge.net\" /> <style type=\"text/css\"> #svg {display:block;}</style> <title>Sample Document</title> </head> <body> <h1>My First HTML Document with SVG</h1> <div id=\"svg\"> <svg width=\"100\" height=\"100\"> <circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"40\" stroke=\"green\" stroke-width=\"4\" fill=\"yellow\" /></svg></div> </body></html>";
        Document document = pdfCreator.createDocument(html);
        pdfCreator.create(document);
    }

    public void create(Document document) {
        try {
            String outputFile = "D:\\htmlWithSVG.pdf";
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            renderer.setDocument(document, null);
            ChainingReplacedElementFactory chainingReplacedElementFactory = new ChainingReplacedElementFactory();
            chainingReplacedElementFactory.addReplacedElementFactory(new SVGReplacedElementFactory());
            SharedContext sharedContext = renderer.getSharedContext();
            sharedContext.setReplacedElementFactory(chainingReplacedElementFactory);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(os);
            os.close();
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Document createDocument(String xml) {
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        Document document = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = builder.parse(inputSource);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return document;
    }}
```

I have also looked at the following tutorial and the classes `ChainingReplacedElementFactory` and `SVGReplacedElementFactory` are used from that tutorial.

http://www.samuelrossille.com/home/render-html-with-svg-to-pdf-with-flying-saucer.html

Comment: You haven't got an XML string though have you? You've actually got an HTML string.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think that html is also an xml. Actually I have to convert that html into pdf.

Comment: You need to change your thinking then: html is not xml. xhtml is xml though so you could try that instead perhaps.

Comment: @RobertLongson I am sorry. That html was generated using JTidy. So, it is xhtml document.

Comment: No it isn't. It has no namespace definitions. I.e no xmlns="<something>" attributes so it's HTML. It is not valid xhtml.

Comment: Try putting the width and height for the `<svg>` element as a `style="width:xxxpx; height: yyypx;"` attribute rather than as separate `width="xxx"` and `height="yyy"` attributes.